# Проблема с Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, sublime-text-3

Отсутствует всплывающий текст при написании кода в файле Style.css, а в Index.html он работает. В чем может быть проблема ? Раньше просто с этим не сталкивался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пробовали поставить SublimeAllAutocomplete?

Comment: Aliaksandr Pitkevich, не помогло, проверил

Comment: css или sass не работает? попробуйте это еще https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Completions

Comment: может ли это быть связанно с плагином emmet в Sublime Text? Что после его установки вышли такие баги.